# Floating point math. Ruby program not completely running

Tags: ruby, rspec, floating-point

I am having some trouble with one of my ruby problems. I need to build a program that simulates RPN, or stack arithmetic as I've heard it called.

Following is the rspec file in its entirety:

http://pastebin.com/mii9QPD4

Next up is my current code without the attempt at floats:

http://pastebin.com/zGb2E2Xe

If I don't convert the division part into a float, then I will just get back an integer answer, which would be wrong. So in the def value section for division, I attempted:

```
elsif @stack[i] == '/'
            @stack[i-2] = Float(@stack[i-2]) / Float(@stack[i-1])
            @stack.delete_at(i-1)
            @stack.delete_at(i-1)
            answer = @stack[i-2]
            i = i-1
```

I've also tried just multplying the values in those 2 locations by 1.0, but the following happens when I rake:

```
RPNCalculator
  adds two numbers
  adds three numbers
  subtracts the second number from the first number
  adds and subtracts
```

It never finishes. No errors or anything. So I got rid of all the Float/*1.0 stuff and decided to put the Float part up a bit earlier:

```
def push(x)
    x = Float(x)
    @stack.push(x)
end
```

or:

```
def push(x)
    x = x * 1.0
    @stack.push(x)
end
```

and my result when I rake:

```
RPNCalculator
```

It gets stuck there. Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please set your indents to something smaller, like 2 spaces instead of 8.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll format better next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The core of your calculator is this:

```
while i < @stack.size
  if @stack[i].class == Fixnum
    i+=1    
  # elsif branches for the operations...
  end   
end
```

There is no `else` in there so you're assuming that `@stack[i]` is a Fixnum or one of the four operator strings (`'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'`, `'/'`). So what happens to `i` if `@stack[i] == 3.14`? Nothing at all happens to `i` so it ends up in an infinite loop.

If you're going to mix `Fixnum` and `Float` in `@stack`, then you could take advantage of the fact that both of those are `Numeric`:

```
if @stack[i].is_a? Numeric
  i += 1
#...
```

If you start using `Float`s in `@stack`, don't expect your simple equality tests in your spec to pass. Floating point values are subject to precision problems equality tests aren't that useful with floating point values, you have check that the difference between what you get and what you expect is smaller than some acceptable error amount. However, Ruby has a [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) class in the core so you could do this:

```
def push(x)
  @stack.push(x.to_r)
end
```

to use `Rational`s (i.e. fractions) in your calculations and avoid the floating point problem. Of course, this assumes that you'd be inputing integers but that might not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I ended up using an else: i+=1 which continued the loop for me.